# Navigation Based App Question - Beginner iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation

I want to make a simple application and Im wondering which method navigation would be best. The app would need to have a list on the opening screen in table view, you could then select a particular item  on that list to see the detailed view for that item.

Is it then possible to have text and possibly an image appear in the detail view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Most apps behave this way on the iPhone. Look at Contacts, Notes, Photos, Settings, and thousands of other apps.

Apps are composed of multiple views. What you're describing is a navigation-based application with a table view and a custom view (your detail view which contains an image view to display your image and a text view to display your text).

Comment: Thankyou. Do you know of any source code files around to get me started developing this. I want to have about 25 individual items on the table view which then lead to the detailed view

Comment: Hi, for example, see my post. Does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to have any subclass of UIView (like UITextView, UIImageView) in the detail view.

As u r using the navigation based application, the RootViewController will have a table view, and a when a row is selected, (tableview:didRowSelectAtIndexPath:), u can present the detail view which can contain the subviews added to it.

For example, have a look this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007416).

Comment: thankyou, I will check out the drill down example. Is it possible to drill down 3 levels. Ie. The first level is a category of games, the second is a specific game name, the next is the detailed explanation of the games?

Comment: Yes, definitely it is possible... If u have looked at the drill down example, the second level is also a table view. U can add UIViewController at the third level.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do so:

1. List = TableView
   Detail view = Another UIView    (transit / change to another view)
2. List = TableView
   Detail View = TableView Cell enlarged
   e.g. (original: every cell = 40 px,  when clicked, that specific cell = 100px)
3. List = TableView
   Detail View = Popups
   e.g. Using the Popup with a black arrow.  But only support very small size

in replying your question, **YES**, all 3 ways can use image & text, and even audio & video & openGL.
i.e. All three use view subclass from UIView.  The View class is different but the how-to is the same.

^^